# Can a locally compact group with closed singleton be countable but not discrete?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, baire-category, locally-compact-groups, group-theory

**Problem: Prove if a locally compact group $(G,*)$ contains a closed singleton then it must be either discrete or uncountable**

Proof Given: Assuming $G$ is countable we can write $G =  \displaystyle \bigcup_{g \in G} {g}  $. If every $\{ g\}$ has empty interior then this is $G$ expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense sets, which is not allowed. So there must be some $\{ g_0\}$ with nonempty interior, which implies $\{ g_0\}$ is open and hence each $\{ g\} = g g_0 ^{-1}\{ g_0\}$ is open and $G$ is discrete.

My problem with this proof is I don't see why $G$ cannot be expressed in this way, as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. I know if $G$ is hausdorff we can invoke a version of the Baire Category Theorem to get the result. But can we somehow prove $G$ must be hausdorff with the given information, or is there a version of the theorem with weaker requirements? Ideally someone could give me an example of a countable, non-discrete locally compact non-hausdorff group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with your last question: a typical example of a countable, non-discrete
locally compact non-Hausdorff group would be the integers with the indiscrete
topology.

No example is likely to be more interesting than that, since every T<sub>0</sub>
topological group is a Tychonoff space.

That also explains the proof: a topological group with a closed singleton is
T<sub>1</sub> by homogeneity and therefore also T<sub>2</sub>.

---

**Addendum:**
That T<sub>0</sub> implies T<sub>2</sub> can be proved as follows. 
Take $g \ne e$, such that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $e$ that 
does not include $g$. There is a neighbourhood $V \ni e$ such that
$VV \subset U$. Then $V$ and $gV^{-1}$ are disjoint neighbourhoods of 
$e$ and $g$, and $g^{-1}V$ and $V^{-1}$ are disjoint neighbourhoods of
$g^{-1}$ and $e$ respectively.

Comment: Is the proof that $T_1$ implies Hausdorff that if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $e$ then for any $g \ne e$ we have that $W = U - \{ g,g^{-1} \}$ is also an open neighborhood of $e$ and that $gW$ is an open neighborhood of $g$ not containing $e$ so the topology is Hausdorff?

Comment: I don't think that gives you disjoint neighbourhoods.